# Creating a dynamic variable and use it further in python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

*First post*
Hi, I m new to python. I have the following code

```
class Signal_4():
def __init__(self,x1, y1):
    self.x1 = x1
    self.y1 = y1

def draw(self):
    v1 = 0
    v2 = 0
    for i in range(4):
        v1 = self.x1 + 10*i
        v2 = v1 + 10
        points= [v1,self.y1,v2,self.y1+10]
        setattr(mod, str(self)+'_{}'.format(i),Frame1.create_oval(points, outline="black",fill="black"))

Y5 = Signal_4(360, 20)
Y5.draw()
```

If you will run this, in the Frame1 (I have the window sectioned in 3 frames) it will appear 4 black dots.
Now I want to use the dynamic variable (eg Y5_0) to make the dot blue/red/any other color.
But when I run the code, everything works perfectly, except for the part where I try to change the dot color "NameError: name 'Y5_0' is not defined".

If someone can help with:
A suggestion on how to use the dynamic variable further OR if the best practice is to make each dot a static variable, it will be much appreciated.

PS: I m trying to find a solution not to write 300 lines of code, meaning 68 variables

Comment: Please edit the full error message into your question.  Is this the full code you are running? If mot please edit a [mre] into your question, which i can paste into a file and run __without adding anything__ to see the same error message.

Comment: Please also when you do the setattr call print the name of the attribute you are creating to confirm it is Y5_0